# Can you Windows Auth to Basic Auth?

Tags: authentication, blazor

I'm developing a blazor web application that will use windows authentication. The web application requires data from another web service. Basic authentication is required on the web service. The web application and web service are in the same domain using the same domain for authentication. Is there a way to take the windows auth credential that the web application will possess and convert it to the basic auth required by the web service?

I am aware that the windows auth credential does not contain the password and basic auth needs a password. I cannot change the authentication scheme of the web service. I cannot spin up a new instance of the web service with a different authentication mechanism. I can't use basic authentication for the web application. The web service requires that the web application connects with it using the logged in users credentials for logging purposes ie. can't just use a service account to connect to the web service. I am open to using a different authentication mechanism for the web application with comparable security to windows auth if it will work, SSO preferred.

I believe this is technically infeasible but would welcome any evidence to the contrary.